# Raspbian Jessie unable to log in after password change

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, login

On a fresh install of Raspbian Jessie I tried to changed the password once in the `raspi-config` and one time in the UI (2 fresh installs). When I reboot I was never able to get past the log in screen. Not with my new password, nor with the default `pi:raspberry` credentials.

Any one else noticed this issue? Any fix for this?

I added a new user manually and logged out of the default loggedin user (pi), tried to log in, again "wrong password".

Note: This is on a new Raspberry Pi 2B with a 16GB Sd card.

Comment: In order to rule out the obvious are the cap locks on?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yes caps lock is of. This is my 4th RPI but the first with Jessie, never had problems on other distro's.

Comment: I am totally serious, i once charged 120 for an in person support visit for the caps lock.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Easy money ;) but no idea why this is a problem? Is it just me?

Comment: What characters etc did you put in your password, and have you tried different passwords?

Comment: @Wilf I tried multiple usernames and passwords combinations. This is what I tried: lowercasetext, Camelcase123, Camelcase123character, UPERCASE123UPERCASE

Comment: Is it possible that you changed the root account password and not the `pi` account password?

Comment: @PradhyumnaNarain No, and since this is an question of about 4 years ago, this issue is probably fixed in newer versions :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I discovered that the issue was because my password have special characters and the default keyboard layout is English(UK), so when I thought I'm typing @ I really is typing ". I changed the keyboard layout to English(US) using raspi-config and changed the password after that, and it worked perfectly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The first thing the raspberry pi requests when you start it up is to change the default password. If, for example, you choose a password with he letter # in it, you will be stuffed if you then change your keyboard to a US keyboard. You will never be able to log in.
The Shift-3 key sequence is £ The British currency symbol, once you change to a US keyboard, it becomes a # symbol.